# Custom style for Slider causing it to turn blue when selected

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I have created the following style for the `Slider` control which basically allows me to hide the track, and set the thumb color.

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Static.Foreground" Color="#FFE5E5E5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFDCECFC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7Eb4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFDAECFC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Static.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbHorizontalTop" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 0,6 C0,6 5.5,0 5.5,0 5.5,0 11,6 11,6 11,6 11,18 11,18 11,18 0,18 0,18 0,18 0,6 0,6 z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stretch="Fill" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbHorizontalBottom" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 0,12 C0,12 5.5,18 5.5,18 5.5,18 11,12 11,12 11,12 11,0 11,0 11,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,12 0,12 z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stretch="Fill" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Track.Border" Color="#FFD6D6D6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderThumb.Track.Background" Color="#FFE7EAEA"/>
    <Style x:Key="RepeatButtonTransparent" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbHorizontalDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 0,12 C0,12 5.5,18 5.5,18 5.5,18 11,12 11,12 11,12 11,0 11,0 11,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,12 0,12 z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stretch="Fill" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}" StrokeThickness="1" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Fill="{x:Null}" Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,2" Placement="Top" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Fill="{x:Null}" Height="4" Margin="0,2,0,0" Placement="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}" Height="4.0" Margin="5,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="center">
                    <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Height="4.0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                    <!--<Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>-->
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="18" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="11"/>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalTop}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="5,2,5,0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalBottom}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="5,0,5,2"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_SelectionRange" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Thumb" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbVerticalLeft" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 6,11 C6,11 0,5.5 0,5.5 0,5.5 6,0 6,0 6,0 18,0 18,0 18,0 18,11 18,11 18,11 6,11 6,11 z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbVerticalRight" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M 12,11 C12,11 18,5.5 18,5.5 18,5.5 12,0 12,0 12,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,11 0,11 0,11 12,11 12,11 z" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Background}" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbVerticalDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path x:Name="grip" Data="M0.5,0.5 L18.5,0.5 18.5,11.5 0.5,11.5z" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Background}" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Border}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.MouseOver.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Pressed.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="grip" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderVertical" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0,0,2,0" Placement="Left" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="4"/>
                <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="2,0,0,0" Placement="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="4"/>
                <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Background}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="center" Margin="0,5" Width="4.0">
                    <Canvas Margin="-1,-6">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Visibility="Hidden" Width="4.0"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="11" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="18"/>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalLeft}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="2,5,0,5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalRight}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="0,5,2,5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_SelectionRange" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Thumb" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="HiddenTrackSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Foreground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SliderHorizontal}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SliderVertical}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

It works as expected for the most part, except that the thumb turns blue when the control is selected either by mouse input or tabbing through. I have no idea how to get rid of this behavior and could use some help.

[image]
This image shows that the "middle" slider is blue when clearely set to red in XAML (note this slider is currently selected by mouse)

Comment: Addendum If i set `Focusable` to false I get the correct behavior, but would like to avoid that as I would like to create my own focused style at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the IsKeyboardFocused triggers at the very bottom of the `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` collections of the "SliderVertical" and "SliderHorizontal" templates:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderVertical" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0,0,2,0" Placement="Left" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="4"/>
            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="2,0,0,0" Placement="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="4"/>
            <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.Background}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="center" Margin="0,5" Width="4.0">
                <Canvas Margin="-1,-6">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Visibility="Hidden" Width="4.0"/>
                </Canvas>
            </Border>
            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="11" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="18"/>
                </Track.Thumb>
            </Track>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalLeft}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="2,5,0,5"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbVerticalRight}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="0,5,2,5"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_SelectionRange" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
        <!--<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Thumb" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>-->
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Fill="{x:Null}" Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,2" Placement="Top" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Fill="{x:Null}" Height="4" Margin="0,2,0,0" Placement="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Border x:Name="TrackBackground" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}" Height="4.0" Margin="5,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="center">
                <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Height="4.0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </Canvas>
            </Border>
            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                <!--<Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>-->
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="18" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="11"/>
                </Track.Thumb>
            </Track>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalTop}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="5,2,5,0"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="Thumb" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalBottom}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="TrackBackground" Value="5,0,5,2"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopTick" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomTick" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelectionRangeEnabled" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_SelectionRange" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
        <!--<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Thumb" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>-->
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```